# mysql like clause doesnt work against array php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hello am trying to count how many rows are in location column where there names include any of the names which are in the predefined $uk_array.

mysql prints out that I don't have any value in my column "there are ()" that matches a name from the array although there is one "Dublin, Ireland".

Here is the code:

```
    <?php
    include'connect.php';
    $uk_array = array('Liverpool','London','London UK','UK','London',
    'Dublin, Ireland','Manchester','Norwich','United Kingdom','Norwich','Duplin','England','ENGLAND',
    'united kingdom');

    $string = '';

    foreach($uk_array as $term=>$i) {
        $string = $string."location LIKE '%".$i."%' AND";
    }
    $string = substr($string, 0, -5);
    $query="SELECT COUNT(location) as location FROM tweets WHERE $string";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "There are ". $row['location']."";

    }


    ?>
```

Comment: Pay more attention to your logic before writing your code.

Comment: If you do not partially match locations, use `WHERE location IN ('Dublin', 'Liverpool', 'London', ...)` instead of LIKE, its faster and cleaner.

Comment: Missing space. That's all I will say...

Comment: Also: nonbinary string comparisons are case *insensitive* by default. So you do not need to have, for example, "United Kingdom" AND "united kingdom" checked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be doing

```
$string = $string."location LIKE '%".$i."%' OR";
```

Switch the AND operator with the OR operator, otherwise the field has to contain all of the values in uk_array.

Also, you have a typo - Duplin?

Edit: More errors

```
foreach($uk_array as $term=>$i) {
    if($term) $string .= ' OR '; // only append OR if it's not the first one
    $string .= "location LIKE '%".$i."%'";
}
```

Comment: with OR i get this error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''%united kingdom%' at line 1

Comment: Copy it again - that was because you had something like OR%united kingdom% in the query. You need spaces, too.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the **OR** Operator

```
  // change this
  // $string = $string."location LIKE '%".$i."%' AND";
  // to
   $string = $string."location LIKE '%".$i."%' OR";
 // and 
 // $string = substr($string, 0, -5);
 // to
 $string = substr($string, 0, -3);
```